# Sqlcmd Batch Script

Tags: sqlcmd

In my sqlserver project, there are many .sql files in different folders Like
C:\username\EtlcontrolDB\scrip1.sql.........script10.sql
C:\username\configuration\scrip1.sql.........script10.sql
C:\username\Think...........................

My client requirement is, above folders contained sql files execution through single batch script. and sql filenames and filepath  input geting from .txt file and also C:\username this one will be different for each user,remains path is similor to all users,
also i want to execute some folders fully and some folders specific sql files only

Can anyone help me about this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: There are ways of doing what you're proposing, but you're going to have to provide more solid details of what you are working with including any code you have thus far. And please try to focus on just one problem/question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using sqlcmd alone.

You will have to write a batch script in a language such as python that invokes sqlcmd for every .sql file stored in a specified directory. Here is an example in Python (untested!):

```
import subprocess
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def main():
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir('C:\username\EtlcontrolDB\') if isfile(join('C:\username\EtlcontrolDB\',f)) ]
    for f in onlyfiles:
        sqlcmd(f)

def sqlcmd( file ):
    query = open(file).read()
    sqlcommand = 'sqlcmd -Q ' + query + ' -S "Myserver" -U UserName -P Password'
    subprocess.call(sqlcommand)

main()
```